# Puppet Run giving Error: failed to execute puppetrun: ERF12-4252

Tags: puppet, foreman

So as in the title, whenever I try to "Run Puppet" from Foreman I get the following error in the GUI.

This was all due to, in the beginning a configuration error, where activemq needed to be set up. Once that was determined and set up correctly, I then began getting an ERF12-4252 error, that was corresponding to this error message below in the foreman-proxy logs.

W, [2016-10-02T11:12:17.782288 #1796]  WARN -- : Non-null exit code when executing '["/usr/bin/sudo", "-u", "root", "/opt/puppetlabs/bin/mco", "puppet", "runonce", "-I", ""]'
E, [2016-10-02T11:12:17.782431 #1796] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
I, [2016-10-02T11:12:17.782622 #1796]  INFO -- : x.x.x.x - - [02/Oct/2016:11:12:17 -0400] "POST /puppet/run HTTP/1.1" 500 34 0.0054

I was able to finally figure out where the problem was despite the logs being very vague, by adding a shell to the foreman-proxy user, and attempting to run that exact command from the CLI instead of through the Foreman GUI.

Marking this as solved.

Comment: Can you set :log_level to DEBUG in /etc/foreman-proxy/settings.yml, restart foreman-proxy, use the Run Puppet button again and provide the log file please? A 404 might suggest that the Puppet feature is failing to start on the smart proxy, so the log from startup should provide more info.

Comment: Hopefully this sheds some light, but to me everything appears to be doing what it is supposed to. The only thing I left out was the certificate info from the logs as I didn't want to make some of the information printed out from that public. No errors regarding the certs though.

http://pastebin.com/4SsXxwwR

Comment: Here's the paste bin for the logs when "Run Puppet" is attempted from the GUI. http://pastebin.com/nkx63iYy

Comment: Do you have sudo rules set up for foreman-proxy? See the command it's trying to execute.

Comment: I do, and I verified the command it is trying to execute works when run on the command line. I also gave foreman-proxy a bash shell, su to foreman-proxy, and ran the command from the command line and it worked.

Comment: Doesn't appear that mcollective is ever getting the puppet run command from the foreman-proxy. If I run "mco puppet runonce -I <hostname>" from the command line as the foreman-proxy user, everything works fine and as expected. If I "Run Puppet" from the foreman GUI I get "Non-null exit code when executing '["/usr/bin/sudo", "-u", "foreman-proxy", "/opt/puppetlabs/bin/mco", "puppet", "runonce", "-I", "<hostname>"]' then Failed puppet run: Check Log files

At this point should I just submit a bug report to foreman?

Comment: You should try running exactly the same command with the `sudo -u root /opt/puppetlabs/bin/mco` prefix instead of just `mco`. I notice the command changed in your last comment to sudo to the same user - this will still require sudo rules. There's probably little point in filing a bug against the smart proxy as the failing exit code is external to the smart proxy (probably misconfiguration).

Comment: I did as requested and tried to run the exact command found in the foreman-proxy logs, on the command line and it works flawlessly, however the foreman-proxy still gives me this error when trying to run from the foreman GUI. It very well could be a misconfiguration, but none of the logs are being verbose enough to actually troubleshoot that. Foreman-proxy logs below, as well as command run directly.

Comment: This can be closed. I finally found the misconfiguration. The suggested sudoers entry from the quick install documentation didn't work correctly on my system, thus causing the non null return code from /usr/bin/sudo -u root /opt/puppetlabs/bin/mco puppet runonce -I foreman.mattlocal.com. 

This took a good amount of time to track down and was finally found by adding a shell to the foreman-proxy user, and attempting to run using the command above from that user.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

I'll mark this as solved and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all due to, in the beginning a configuration error, where activemq needed to be set up. Once that was determined and set up correctly, I then began getting an ERF12-4252 error, that was corresponding to this error message below in the foreman-proxy logs.

W, [2016-10-02T11:12:17.782288 #1796] WARN -- : Non-null exit code when executing '["/usr/bin/sudo", "-u", "root", "/opt/puppetlabs/bin/mco", "puppet", "runonce", "-I", ""]' E, [2016-10-02T11:12:17.782431 #1796] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files I, [2016-10-02T11:12:17.782622 #1796] INFO -- : x.x.x.x - - [02/Oct/2016:11:12:17 -0400] "POST /puppet/run HTTP/1.1" 500 34 0.0054

I was able to finally figure out where the problem was despite the logs being very vague, by adding a shell to the foreman-proxy user, and attempting to run that exact command from the CLI instead of through the Foreman GUI.